# Why is Firebug saying that $.cookie() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie with jQuery 1.7.1:

```
var global_namesArray = ["Alex", "Bob", "Carmen"];
$.cookie("namesArray", global_namesArray);
```

I retrieve this cookie like this:

```
if ($.cookie("namesArray") != null)
    global_namesArray = $.cookie("namesArray");
```

However, the page's javascript does not load. When I use Firebug to analyze my page, the console reads that $.cookie() is not a function. The error occurs during cookie retrieval I believe. I am sure that I have linked jQuery.

Am I using the jQuery $.cookie() function correctly?

Comment: on the Net tab in Firebug do you get a 200OK response for loading jquery?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery cookie plugin? `cookie` is not a standard jQuery method.

Comment: Also, don't discount the possibility that there's a simple syntax error elsewhere in your JS. especially if that cookie code is inside its own script tag with other code. You might simply be missing a ) or something in the lines above that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.cookie is not a native function for jQuery.  Do you have the [cookie plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) installed?

Edit:
I just tested, and I get this error if I include jQuery but not the cookie plugin:

```
"$.cookie is not a function".
```

You probably just need to add the cookie plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `jquery.cookie.js` is included after `jquery.js`, and that you are not including `jquery.js` more than once.