# Javascript Cookie Undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to fix a problem in a Cookie Javascript code but in the Chrome Console still getting an error in the function. Could someone help me?

```
<script>
        //<![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            console.log( $.cookie("test_cookies_agree"));
            if( $.cookie("test_cookies_agree") != "autorized"){
                $('div.cookies').css('visibility','visible');
            }

            $('.fechar').click(function() {
                $('div.cookies').toggle( "fade", 1000 );
                $.cookie("test_cookies_agree", "autorized", {expires : 10, path : '/' });
                return false;
            });
        });
        Jobber.jobber_url = "http://www.test.com/";
        //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Seriously!  You're getting an error in the console and you don't tell us what that error is?  That's likely the first step in understand what is wrong.

Comment: @brso05: In which case `$.cookie('name') != 'authorized'` will evaluate to false, as `$.cookie('non-existent-cookie')` returns `null`. So yes, the code isn't the best it can be, but that wouldn't cause an error

Comment: @Alexandre Miguel do you have cookie plugin installed?

Comment: @Alexandre Miguel try downloading the separate cookie plugin there is a link in my answer (second link) will take you to download it...

Comment: @jfriend00 the error was only undefined function, i wrote that.

Comment: @AlexandreMiguel - next time, please include the EXACT error message and the tell us exactly which line of code the error occurred on.  Your mistake would have taken 10 seconds for us to recognize if you included the exact error information.  As it is, you made us guess where the error was.  This is part of "efficient debugging" and problem solving.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, i will try to be more specific next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cookie is not a native jquery plugin make sure you install the cookie plugin. [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039744/why-is-firebug-saying-that-cookie-is-not-a-function)

Download cookie plugin [Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Comment: Fantastic, was really that. Thanks ;)